# Asp.net core, HttpClient to reach SOAP service with POST request

Tags: c#, soap, .net-core

I'm trying to reach 3rd party SOAP WS using `HttpClient`.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{
  HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
  httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
  HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), myUrl);
  request.Content = new StringContent(myXmlString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
  request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction",https://actionNameOfWs);
  HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
  if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) return new OkResult();
  else return new ObjectResult(response.StatusCode);
}
```

At this point everything breaks with `TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled`, which is not really a task cancel, but a connection timeout. I can send the same POST request over `https` with SOAP UI just fine, so connection to WS is not a problem. I can send POST request over `http` with code above just fine. But once I'm trying code above to send POST over `https`, I'm getting connection timeout. So, where's the catch?

My environment is:
OS: Linux Mint 16.04
.Net Core: 1.0.1

Comment: What is `result` in the OP

Comment: Misspelled request.

Answer (score 1):

You may be mixing async and blocking calls. `.Result` is a blocking call that can lead to deadlocks which may be causing the timeout when mixed with async calls. Make the calling action async all the way through.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login() {
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
    var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, myUrl);
    request.Content = new StringContent(myXmlString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", https://actionNameOfWs);
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) return Ok();
    else return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode);
}
```

I would also suggest that you inspect the raw request being sent and its response.

Comment: Nope, getting exactly the same exception with await as well.

Comment: @JohnSmith, You will need to show more code. show higher up in the code stack that calls the code in original example.

Comment: @JohnSmith also try to extend the time out period of the client eg: `client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);`

Comment: I've added more code, but there's not much to look at. It's just a controller being called by my app to use 3rd party auth.

Comment: @JohnSmith I've refactored the method to be async all the way through. I am still convinced it has something to do with mixed calls. That or it has to do with the certificate for the https